# Micronaut jasync configuring SSL Mode Required fails

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-data, jasync-sql

I'm trying to configure Micronaut SQL jasync with the following configuraiton:

```
jasync:
  client:
    host: myhost
    port: 5432
    database: mydb
    username: myusername
    password: mypassword
    maxActiveConnections: 10
    ssl:
      mode: require
```

When I try to connect t the database I get the following error:

```
Message: 'void com.github.jasync.sql.db.SSLConfiguration.<init>(com.github.jasync.sql.db.SSLConfiguration$Mode, java.io.File)'
Path Taken: new FaultApiController([SimpleFaultData faultData]) --> new SimpleFaultData([Connection client]) --> new JasyncPostgreSQLClientFactory([JasyncPoolConfiguration jasyncPoolConfiguration])
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.micronaut.configuration.jasync.JasyncPostgreSQLClientFactory]
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.github.jasync.sql.db.SSLConfiguration.<init>(com.github.jasync.sql.db.SSLConfiguration$Mode, java.io.File)'
```

Looking on github I found the following issue that sounds similar but shows as resolved:
https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-sql/issues/104

Am I configuring the jasync connector incorrectly or is this bug still present? Also, I can't figure out how to implement the work around.  There doesn't seem to be enough information for me to understand it. Any clarifications or suggested work arounds would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Micronaut 2.5.7 is not compatible with the latest version of jasync (1.2.2).  Also, Micronaut-SQL is not managing the jasync dependency.  An issues has been filed:

https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-sql/issues/474

To work around this, drop back to the 1.1.4 version of jasync.